# Approximation of a square root of e with a precision of $10^{-3}$ using Taylor formula

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function, approximation

So, I have to approximate a value of square root of e: $\sqrt{e}$ with a precision of $10^{-3}$. 
I have calculated the first and second derivative:
So instead of $\sqrt{e}$ I need to approximate the value for  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{e}}$$ If I follow the formula given by one of the users: $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
I gues the result is the same then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you the general formula for a taylor series of a function centered around a point?

Comment: The derivative of $\sqrt{e}$ is zero. It's just a number. Instead, try finding the Taylor series of $e^x$.

Comment: Yes, I know the formula, but how to apply it here? No point is given.

Comment: According to what @Infiaria said, you can use $$e^x=1+x+{x^2\over 2}+{x^3\over 6}+{x^4\over 24}+{x^5\over 120}+\cdots$$

Comment: Ok, she is right. But what should I do with these series?

Comment: Set $x = \frac 12$.

Comment: Precision is the *accuracy* by which the computer completes elementary arithmetic operations, i.e., addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. The accuracy of an algorithm is the largest relative error committed. When you write "precision" do you really mean accuracy, i.e. you need to compute an approximation $A$ us that $|T-A| \leq 10^{-3} |T|$ where $T = e^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is your target value?

Comment: Yes, only it's e^(-1/4). But I don't understand why are you multiplying 10^(-3) by T? Also, is there any general way how can I find which order expansion would be right for the given inequality? Or I must guess? Also on Taulor series you must multiply derivative by (x-c) and c usually is given, but on this exercise there is no point c, what should I do in this case?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question which should address all issues. When you a comment to your own post (question/answer) you must include the user name of the recipient, i.e., write @CarlChristian to notify me. I only found your message because I manually went to this question. If you comment on a post then the author will automatically be notified.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$e^x
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}
$,
the error after $n$ terms is
$e_n(x)
=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}
$.

If $ 0 < x < 1$,
the error can be bounded as,

$\begin{array}\\
e_n(x)
&=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}\\
&\lt\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac1{n!}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} x^k\\
&=\dfrac{x^n}{n!(1-x)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n!2^{n-1}}
\qquad\text{if } x = \frac12\\
\end{array}
$

This is $\frac1{192}$ for $n=4$
and
$\frac1{1920}$ for $n=5$,
so $n=5$ will work.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you add 1-x to the equation. What's it for?

Comment: @IevaBrakmane The $1-x$ in the denominator comes from the sum of an infinite geometric series being $\frac{a}{1-r}$, with $a = x^n$ and $r = x$ here.

Comment: What ro do if I have to do an approximation of e^(-1/4)? Then the value of x will fluctuate according to n being an even or odd number.

Comment: $e^{-1/4}$ is a constant, so compute it.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
so
$$e^{0.5}=\sqrt{e}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{0.5^n}{n!}$$
now find the $n$ according to

$$\frac{0.5^n}{n!}<10^{-3}$$

Comment: You have to make sure that the following terms do not push the error above 0.001.

Comment: yes, My answer as a hint

Comment: So for me starting from n=4 the inequality is true, because 0.0615/256<0.001, but the previous poster states that only starting from n=5 do the approximation holds with a precision of $10^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fundamental issues which have yet to be addressed.

In general, our goal is to compute a target value $T \in \mathbb{R}$. Typically, we cannot compute the exact value, so we settle for an approximation $A$. The error is by definition $E = T-A$. The relative error is by definition $R = (T-A)/T$. The relative error is only defined when $T \not =0$. The accuracy of the approximation $A$ is the absolute value of the relative error $R$, i.e., the real number $|R|$.

The use of the word precision is not correct in this context. In numerical analysis, the word precision is used almost exclusively when stating the accuracy of the elementary arithmetic operations. This accuracy is called the machine precision. It is hardware dependent.

Computing $T = \sqrt{e}$ with an accuracy of $\tau = 10^{-3}$ means to find $A$ such that $$|R| = \frac{|T-A|}{|T|} \leq \tau.$$
No more and no less. Now, let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. By Taylor's formula, there exists a $\xi \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that
$$ e^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{j!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j + \frac{e^{\xi}}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}.$$ 
This formula is the foundation for our work. It is convenient to do the Taylor expansion at the point $x_0 =0$ rather than anywhere else, simply because all relevant derivatives can be evaluated exactly at $x_0=1$. We therefore focus on the approximation $A_n$ given by $$A_n = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{j!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j.$$ We must bound the relative error $R_n$ given by 
$$ R_n = \frac{T - A_n}{T}.$$ The error $E_n = T - A_n$ satisfies
$$ |E_n| = |T - A_n| \leq \frac{e^{\xi}}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$
We do not know the exact value of $\xi$. Fortunately, it also irrelevant, because $x \rightarrow e^x$ is increasing. It follows that $$e^{\xi} \leq e^{\frac{1}{2}} = T = |T|.$$ It follows that
$$ |E_n| \leq \frac{|T|}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$
or equivalently
$$ |R_n| \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}.$$
It is now straight forward to verify that $n=4$ is the smallest value such that $$ \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} \leq \tau = 10^{-3}.$$

Comment: I have a few questions still. 1) Why, in order to get relative error, we must divide  by T? 2) ∈(0,1/2): Why we choose interval to the left to 1/2? In case of power -1/4 what  should we choose? 3) Entirely don't understand the formula, that is foundation of everything that follows. What is n in this case?

Comment: @IevaBrakmane 1) By definition, the error is $E = T - A$ and the relative error is $R = (T-A)/T$. 2) We do the Taylor expansion at $x_0=0$ because this is the only point where we can easily and explicitly compute all derivatives of $f(x) = e^x$. These derivative are needed to determine the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ for $f$ at the point $x_0$. 3) This is Taylor's formula for $f$ at the point $x_0 = 0$. The object of the exercise is to determine a suitable value of $n$, the degree of the Taylor polynomial which will be used to approximate $f(\frac{1}{2})$.